# how can i access my application deployed on my docker wildfly images

Tags: java, deployment, docker, wildfly

I try to test a simple application firstWebApp.war deployed on a docker wildfly images

my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD firstWebApp.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

After docker build... and docker run... the server is started an the project is deployed I can see this message on the docker terminal

```
WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "firstWebApp.war" (runtime-name : "firstWebApp.war")
13:50:11,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
```

now i need to test my application i can't find the address of the deployed..
any one can help me please ?

Comment: yes effectively :) have you any idea please

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access it via your host's local IP: `http://localhost:8080/firstWebApp` .

Just to clarify: the other IP is for the management interface (Admin console), which is available by default only to local IPs (127.0.0.1 for the Docker container). So, you are not able to access the Admin console, unless you override the CMD instruction as per the documentation. Basically:

> docker run -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0

Reference: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/

Comment: but when i try to run this command, i have this message $ docker run -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/domain.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/domain.sh": stat C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/domain.sh: no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 49fb18c25f236e183811f31ce5f8193058006eba7e8519206269b9462645725a: [8] System error: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/domain.sh": stat C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/domain.sh: no such file or directory

Comment: Why domain.sh? You should use standalone.sh.

Comment: By the way: aren't you able to access the application on port 8080, as in the first URL I posted?

Comment: no i can't ! $ docker run -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh": stat C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh: no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 002908b24f844c3ef3996c183b31b670f933c8c359aad46aed5ec01175b5bf59: [8] System error: exec: "C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh": stat C:/Program Files/Git/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh: no such file or directory

Comment: I meant: using your original command, the one that starts Wildfly correctly, aren't you able to access the first address I posted? http://localhost:8080/firstWebApp -- You should not need to pass other options, unless you need to access the admin console (which is probably not the case).

Comment: with the command docker run -it firstWebApp 
Wildfly starts but i can't access using the address  localhost:8080/firstWebApp

Comment: What is "I can't access"? You get a 404, or you get a "server doesn't exist", or ... ? Also, are you able to run other Docker containers for images building on top of Wildfly? Try this one out: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: i think i find solution i tried to acces to may application with the address of the virtual machine http://192.168.99.100:8080/firstWebApp/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the docker quickstart on windows, docker will start a VM and tell you the IP of that VM. You should be able to access it on that IP.